# LeafletJS map sometimes doesn't load with Google Adsense adbox and its script. After removing it goes away

Tags: html, css, adsense

LeafletJS map sometimes doesn't load with Google Adsense adbox and its script. After removing it goes away. I honestly don't know why its occuring? Can I be sure that it is something to do with the script running and maybe not finishing? How do I make it so that the rest of the page runs and the script runs.

I really have no idea what is happening. Could I get some tips on what I should do?

My Code: (I believe that only this is necessary. I do not have any other scripts besides Adsense scripts.)

```
<body>
<div>
ADSENSE SCRIPTS ARE ALL IN HERE
</div>

{% include map.html %}
</body>
```

**EDIT: It tends to do this when the ad loads before the map. Sometimes when the ad loads before the map it cancels out the maps loading. How can I combat this?**

Comment: If you could share how you are doing it, then we can determine if there is an error or not